# How to get tax amount of product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, taxes

I have called API to calculate Tax for products, I need to show the tax amount for each and every product individually . How can i make it possible? can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: which API endpoint you are consuming?

Comment: Tax calculation API,  this is a confidential API .

Comment: oh I thought its from default magento

Comment: No its not default. can u help me to get tax amount for individual product? @RamkishanSuthar

Comment: @ASHWINI MURTHY Did you able to display the Tax amount? Please post your finds I am also looking for the same.

Comment: @TejasShah this is what i did to display tax amount.extension->Model->Sales->Total->Quote->Tax.php 
under collect() I called my API and result i stored it in one variable called custom.
Then i assigned my variable values to magento tax vaiables
`code`$total->setTaxAmount($custom);
$total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $custom);
$total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $custom);`code`

all these things in custom extension.

Comment: @ASHWINIMURTHY, using product id can we get tax amount?